# Recuperar resultado de una consulta en cakephp3

Tags: cakephp

Hola a todos como estan veran tengo la siguiente consulta en cakephp

```
$query = $this->PreguntasAlternativas->find();
    $query->select(['id_alternativa' => $query->func()->max('id_alternativa')
            ])->where(['id_pregunta' => $idquestion]);
```

esto me retorna un arreglo asi

```
query(array) 
   0(object)
      id_alternativa(null)
```

y lo que quiero es sacar el valor que me devuelve para luego hacer una validacion con es pues no se como recuperar el valor que me devuelve la consulta para hacer algo asi

```
if($query == null){
        $result = 1;
    }else{
        $result = $query->first()+1;
    }
```

eso estuve intendo pero no pasa por el if ayuda por favor gracias!!!!!

Comment: coloca lo que te devuelve print_r($query), para saber la estructura de tu  arreglo

Comment: Hice eso y me muestra esto `Cake\ORM\Query Object ( [(help)] => This is a Query object, to get the results execute or iterate it. [sql] => SELECT (MAX(id_alternativa + 1)) AS `id_alternativa` FROM pregunta_alternativa PreguntasAlternativas WHERE id_pregunta = :c0 [params] => Array ( [:c0] => Array ( [value] => 7 [type] => integer [placeholder] => c0 ) )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi solucion fue esta cambiar la estructura de mi query

```
$query = $this->PreguntasAlternativas->find('all', ['conditions' => ['id_pregunta' => $idquestion]]);
    $result = $query->max('id_alternativa');
    if(!$result['id_alternativa']){
        $result['id_alternativa'] = 1;
    } else {
        $result['id_alternativa'] += 1;
    }
```

Graciasss